# SKScene не всегда всё показывает все элементы

Tags: swift, spritekit

У меня при добавлении не всегда показывает все элементы. Каждый раз полный рандом. Одни элементы появляются другие исчезают. Вот код:

```
        sceneForViewGame = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: backgImage)


    sceneForViewGame.position = CGPoint(x:0, y:0)

    numberForViewGame = SKLabelNode(text: "1:20")
    numberForViewGame.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width/2, y: frame.size.height - 30)
    sceneForViewGame.addChild(numberForViewGame)

    let node:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: questionOne.image)
    node.size = CGSize(width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height*2/5)
    node.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width/2, y: frame.size.height*1.5/2)
    sceneForViewGame.addChild(node)

    let questionLabel:SKLabelNode = SKLabelNode(text: questionOne.question)
    questionLabel.position = CGPoint(x:frame.size.width/2, y:frame.size.height/2-20)
    sceneForViewGame.addChild(questionLabel)
    self.addChild(sceneForViewGame)
```

Comment: "Одни элементы есть, а другие есть" - тогда в чем проблема? :D

Comment: По коду проблем не вижу. Очень помогли бы пару скриншотов: когда все ок, и когда что-то не показывает. Возможно проблема в `zPosition`. Добавьте код, где вы создаете сцену.

Comment: @kelin, если была бы проблема в zPostition, то он бы каждый раз устанавливал бы элемента на одном уровне. А не рандомно. Скриншоты чуть позже скину

Comment: Если у элементов не установлена zPosition, то они появляются на одном уровне. В зависимости от момента создания объекта (и это не та последовательность, что в коде, разница может идти на доли секунды), они могут перекрывать друг друга и, соответственно, некоторые из них не видны.